# Does PostgreSQL have a built in feature to delete old records every minute or hour, like delete all records older than 2 years and check every hour

Tags: database, postgresql, sql-delete

Does Postgres have any features to support aging-out old records?

Like the title says, I want to delete all records that are older than 2 years old, and have it check every few minutes or hours. I've seen posts that are years old saying no, but perhaps things have changed.

Comment: `delete from the_table where create_at < current_timestamp - interval '2 years'` another option is to partition the table by a timestamp column, then drop the partitions.

Comment: Already asked in answered in https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/106827/automatic-aging-out-deletion-of-old-records-in-postgres.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In addition to the [good answer on DBA Stack Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/106827/automatic-aging-out-deletion-of-old-records-in-postgres), let me add this:

It is not necessary to delete the rows every couple of minutes. Rather, you hide them from queries.

Take this simple example:

```
CREATE TABLE realdata (
   id bigint PRIMARY KEY,
   payload text,
   create_time timestamp with time zone DEFAULT current_timestamp NOT NULL
) PARTITION BY RANGE (create_time);

CREATE VIEW visibledata AS
   SELECT * FROM realdata
   WHERE create_time > current_timestamp - INTERVAL '2 years';
```

The view is simple enough that you can `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE` on it directly; no need for triggers.

Now all data will automagically vanish from `visibledata` after two years.

Occasionally you launch a clean-up job that simply drops all partitions older than two years.

Comment: That does not solve the problem. Usually deleting old data happens because it has performance cost and this solution only hide the problem

Comment: @omidh My answer says: "Occasionally, you launch a clean-up job." Of course you want to get rid of the data eventually, but it is good for performance if you don't have to do that right away, all the time.

Comment: Oh sorry yes you are right, I missed that.

Comment: @uberrebu I don't see any connection to this question. Perhaps you should ask a new one.

Comment: same usecase, this is just an example usecase of question; feel free not to answer

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no: things have not changed for this.

Comment: so how do you handle monthly and yearly quotas for paid users? for example users is allowed to post 10 blogs per month, every month you need to start from zero. How will you do this? for thousands of paid users?